# How can run recursive function on multiple Level array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays one is `$apiRes` and second is `$mappData` i want to match  fields exist in **mappData** array and assign value of **apiRes** to match field.

Note:  response of api may have different and mapdata array will change according to api response My two array and output format :

```
<?php
 $apiRes = [ 
 [
   'firstname' => 'first name des',
   'title' => "title des",
   'category' => 1,
   'result' => 
     [
      0 => [
          'name' => 'Masterpass',
           'skill' => 'low level one'
         ],
      1 => [
          'name' => 'Visa',
          'skill' => 'low level two'
      ],
      2 => [
        'name' => 'Pocketpos',
        'skill' => 'low level three'
    ],   
    ],
   'list' => [
       'product_name'=>'product name',
        'amount' => [
            'currency'=>'$',
            'kind'   => 'kind'
        ]
   ],  
   'priority' => 'Low',
   'visible_to' => 'Everyone',
  ]
];
 $mappData  =  [
    0 =>  [
      "src_field" => "firstname",
      "target_field" => "new1519110449758",
      "src_field_data_type" => "string"
    ],
    1 => [
      "src_field" => "result.name",
      "target_field" => "new1519110811942",
      "src_field_data_type" => "string"
    ],
    2 =>  [
      "src_field" => "list.product_name",
      "target_field" => "new1519110451708",
      "src_field_data_type" => "string"
    ],
    3 =>  [
      "src_field" => "list.amount.currency",
      "target_field" => "new1517556165360",
      "src_field_data_type" => "string"
    ]

    ];
```

**My final output should be:**

```
$output = [
  "new1519110449758" => "first name des",
  "new1519110451708" => "product name",
  "new1517556165360" => "$",
  "new1519110811942" =>  [
    0 => "Masterpass",
    1 => "Visa",
    2 => "Pocketpos"

  ]
];
```

Please help 
Thanks

Comment: what've you tried so far?

Comment: @Noman i want to receive final output from two array

Comment: @Noman understand?

Comment: Clear, but you have to try something before asking here

Comment: @Pierre yeah i have try multiple times through recursive function and without recursion please see

Comment: Don't see anything looking like code

Comment: @Pierre this is code here:

 foreach ($mappData as $mapKey => $mapValue) {
         //print_r($mapValue);
         $finalArray = [];
         $src_field =    $mapValue['src_field'];
         $target_field = $mapValue['target_field'];
         $explodeField = explode('.',$src_field);
         echo $target_field; echo "<br>";
    }

Comment: @Pierre can you make output according to above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your mappData slightly as it's difficult to know how to deal with the `result.name` element as it's repeated.  What I've done is change it so that it's `*result.name` and it uses the fact there is an `*` in it to mean there are multiple values.

I've tried to comment the code with enough to explain each bit, the main principle is using a recursive routine to go through each level of the array one step at a time.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$apiRes = [
    [
        'firstname' => 'first name des',
        'title' => "title des",
        'category' => 1,
        'result' =>
        [
            0 => [
                'name' => 'Masterpass',
                'skill' => 'low level one'
            ],
            1 => [
                'name' => 'Visa',
                'skill' => 'low level two'
            ],
            2 => [
                'name' => 'Pocketpos',
                'skill' => 'low level three'
            ],
        ],
        'list' => [
            'product_name'=>'product name',
            'amount' => [
                'currency'=>'$',
                'kind'   => 'kind'
            ]
        ],
        'priority' => 'Low',
        'visible_to' => 'Everyone',
    ]
];
$mappData  =  [
    0 =>  [
        "src_field" => "firstname",
        "target_field" => "new1519110449758",
        "src_field_data_type" => "string"
    ]
    ,
    1 => [
        "src_field" => "*result.name",
        "target_field" => "new1519110811942",
        "src_field_data_type" => "string"
    ],
    2 =>  [
        "src_field" => "list.product_name",
        "target_field" => "new1519110451708",
        "src_field_data_type" => "string"
    ],
    3 =>  [
        "src_field" => "list.amount.currency",
        "target_field" => "new1517556165360",
        "src_field_data_type" => "string"
    ]

];

$result = [];

// Process next element of the array
function getArrayElement ( $next, $data, $array = false )   {
    // Extract key for this level
    $key = array_shift($next);
    // If starts with * then this means there are multiple of them
    if ( $key[0] == "*" ){
        $nextArray = true;
        // remove from current key
        $key = substr($key,1);
    }
    else    {
        $nextArray = false;
    }

    if ( $array ){
        $res = [];
        // extract the data from each element at this level
        foreach ( $data as $read )  {
            $res[] = $read[$key];
        }
        $data = $res;
    }
    else    {
        // Fetch the element for the key for this level
        $data = $data [ $key ];
    }
    // If there are more levels to deal with then repeat this method
    if ( count($next) > 0 ) {
        $data =  getArrayElement ( $next, $data, $nextArray );
    }
    return $data;
}

// Flatten out original array if necessary
if ( count($apiRes) == 1 ){
    $apiRes = $apiRes[0];
}
// Process each part of lookup
foreach ( $mappData as $element )   {
    // Create an array of the elments broken down into each level
    $map = explode( '.', $element['src_field']);
    $result[$element['target_field']] = getArrayElement($map, $apiRes);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: it's throw error
Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\multilevel\
please check again

Comment: Just remembered that I altered the $apiRes array as well (it was an array of 1 element), I'll add a line of code `$apiRes = $apiRes[0];`

Comment: you removed the outer array from apiRes due to this it's throw error. outer array mean data=>[] can be exist or not. because response will be come from different api's.this response may different or not.

Comment: OK - so changed it to say if the data is one element, then flatten it out.

Comment: Every API's have different response structure.it will be good if it can be handle on multiple level.

Comment: If you give me an example of every possibility and a couple of weeks I can probably make it work.

Comment: i am sending other

Comment: Do you intend to have a different `$mappData` for each service?  This may solve the problem of having different data from different API's

Comment: this mapdata will be show according to api response

Comment: i have updated link http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2038d926bbc399be73fe0cb90be608f4

Comment: mapdata will be change like this according to above api link
 "src_field" => "getResponse.data.result.firstname",
                "target_field" => "new1519110449758",
                "src_field_data_type" => "string"

Comment: Please suggest best

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7c8f871d277c9cfaff524a0a5700a95cc6c850b2

Comment: You need to make sure your mappData is correct - you were missing the getuserinforesponse level out of the first 3 items 
- change to something like "getuserinforesponse.result.profileid" and it works!

Comment: is it possible to handle without asterisk add in mapData if multiple objects exist? because i am not  handling * in mapData

Comment: If the fact it's an asterisk is a problem,then change it to any other character.

Comment: can you check this. because add any character is difficult 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924786/how-can-attach-if-multiple-repeat-object-in-array-using-jsonschemagenerator-in

Comment: I've updated the code, moving the * to the level above ( see `"src_field" => "*result.name",`).

Comment: Now only one problem is character. if it solves than this script run successful

Comment: v very Thanks i can check with different possible scenarios.

Comment: Thanks helpful, awesome,Great solution. Appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165752/discussion-between-john-and-nigel-ren).